# SQL select records with non zero parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a problem with this SQL query:

```
SELECT relname, cast(n_tup_ins AS numeric) / (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) AS ins_pct, 
                cast(n_tup_upd AS numeric) / (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) AS upd_pct, 
                cast(n_tup_del AS numeric) / (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) AS del_pct
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
ORDER BY relname;
```

This query gets characteristics of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations for every table in PostgreSQL base. This is big base and for many tables 
**(n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) = 0**. I tried to detect it by setting **WHERE expr IS NOT NULL** but it still shows error: "Division by zero". Any ideas how to rebuild this query to select records that has non zero sum for **(n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [case-expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html):

```
SELECT relname, 
case 
  when (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) > 0 then
    cast(n_tup_ins AS numeric) / (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) 
  else 
    null 
end AS ins_pct 
FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE ins_pct is not null
ORDER BY relname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT relname, 
CASE WHEN (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) > 0 THEN cast(n_tup_ins AS numeric) / (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) ELSE 0 END AS ins_pct,
CASE WHEN (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) > 0 THEN cast(n_tup_upd AS numeric) / (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) ELSE 0 END AS upd_pct,
CASE WHEN (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) > 0 THEN cast(n_tup_upd AS numeric) / (n_tup_del + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) ELSE 0 END AS upd_pct
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
ORDER BY relname;
```